# Unsigned integer overflow in Rust

Tags: rust, arithmetic-expressions

I am a beginner to Rust. In the code:

`println!("{}", 4400202385408u64 * 34359738368u64);`

The rust compiler gives me the following error:

```
error: attempt to multiply with overflow
```

despite the fact that the result of the multiplication is within `std::u64::MAX`

Can someone point me to what is happening?

Comment: I don't know if either you are very bad at math or if you wrongly deduce the value of `std::u64::MAX` aka `18_446_744_073_709_551_615u64` ~= `10^20` but `4_400_202_385_408 * 34_359_738_368` == `151_189_802_728_868_380_934_144` ~= `10^24` and this is quite bigger ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> despite the fact that the result of the multiplication is within std::u64::MAX

Pretty sure it's not.

Converting to hex, you're doing 0x40080800800 * 0x800000000. They're both individually well over a u32 MAX, so when you multiply them together they're well over a u64 max.

Comment: std::u64::MAX is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (~ 1.8 × 10^19), while the result of the multiplication is 288,300,744,895,889,408 (~ 2.8 × 10^17)

Comment: @DiehardTheTryhard No this is wrong how do you calcul the result ? This is the result when you wrap the multiplication, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3fad2dc6eba287b8b6c1c95b6cf4c8af.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Also, I was using a programmer's calculator, which wraps the result. I will use wrapping_mul in this case